# Accessing the response from PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP how to access the output that is going to be returned to the client? One can insert an unintended newline before the starting php tag or so. When I return my reponse I'd like to check that really that response is returned and nothing else with it. It would be enough if I could check the size of the response returned so far.

Comment: yes, output buffering

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php